# Access to all links on a domain(no hyperlink available)

Tags: internet, http, web-crawler

I need to have access to all links like:

http://www.thewebsitename.com/random_alphanumeric_code1.asp

http://www.thewebsitename.com/random_alphanumeric_code2.asp

etc.for a given website: http://www.thewebsitename.com

(Of course, no hyperlink to such links are available at http://www.thewebsitename.com )

The website doesn't restrict access to the links I want, as they post ads on the internet linking to those weblinks. I just need to keep track of all such links without having to roam all over the internet in search of their ads to get to those links.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Any ideas? anyone?